# Retrieving a zip file from a web site using Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I'm trying to download a zip file from a public web site http://serviciosede.mineco.gob.es/indeco/BDSICE/homebdsice.aspx.

To download the file this site executes a piece of javascript javascript:__doPostBack('lbutton_BdsiceCompleta',").
I have been downloading manually by clicking on this button, but I would like to do it via Excel VBA.

I'm stuck at retrieving the zip file.

```vb
Dim StrWebpage As String
StrWebpage = "http://serviciosede.mineco.gob.es/indeco/BDSICE/homebdsice.aspx"
 
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    
Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 
With objIE
    .Navigate StrWebpage ' Main page
    .Visible = 1
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents:   Loop
 
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    Set HTMLDoc = .Document
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set frame = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("lbutton_BdsiceCompleta")
    Call frame.execScript("lbutton_BdsiceCompleta", "JavaScript")
        
End With
```

Comment: Have you checked for the file in your downloads folder?

Comment: I managed to trigger a download dialog by modifying the code but a download dialog appears after "clicking" which I can´t access. Any ideas?                                                               
         With objIE
         .Navigate StrWebpage ' Main page
         .Visible = 0
         Do While .Busy: DoEvents:   Loop
 
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        objIE.Document.getElementById("lbutton_BdsiceCompleta").Click
        End With

Comment: The download dialog seems to be an IE dialog which I can´t access. I found some threads but they seem to be for 32bit versions

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience with that type of automation.  You might look at Selenium Basic which I think has better features for a task like this.